# Mongoose pre save gives me red lines?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

In the picture below red lines indicates error. I have this code inside a typescript file. @types/mongoose is already installed... 
The code works fine.
The error when hovering over the red line: "This implicitly has type 'any' because it has not type annotation"

[image]

Comment: If you mouse-over it or open the errors pane you'd know the exact error message.

Comment: The error when hovering over the red line: "This implicitly has type 'any' because it has not type annotation"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to type `this` explicitly:

```
}).pre("save", function(this: Type, next) {
```

where `Type` is the type `this` should be.

The caller side does not change - the first `this` argument is removed during compilation.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters-in-callbacks

Comment: Perfekt, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: as I check through index.d.ts inside mongoose types. everything is setup correctly. I can't understand why it don't know type of this by generics defined why creating schema

Answer (score 6):

}).pre< Type >("save", function(next) {

this is another option: Type is the type this should be

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Schema<SchemaType, Model<SchemaType>>({}).pre<SchemaType>("save",function(next){
    // .... your logic
    next()
    })
```

Model - comes from "mongoose"

for more information follow the mongoose documentation
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/schemas.html